# What is the correct way to import icon to drawable folders in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I used to use plugin [android drawable importer](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin), it had some bugs but it worked fine. But by Android Studio 3.6.1, this plugin began to not working anymore. And now it is also not listed plugin marketplace.

Here is the thing that I want to do; I have an icon on computer. I want to import this icon to correct drawable folders with correct sizing. And sizing should be done automatically.

I know image/vector asset menus. But these do not make what I want. Vector asset menu does not provide png or jpeg. And the image asset menu does not make transparent background.

What is the correct and easiest way to do that? I am not a designer. I can not deal with every icon to every size. This is done automatically by the plugin or android studio itself.

Comment: Have you tried android asset studio ? It is unfortunately only available on web

Comment: Have you tried android asset studio ? It is unfortunately only available on web

Comment: @KudzieChase i try now, it's nice work. But I am searching like this website in android studio like plugin.